# Transform `Arrays.stream(…).collect(…)` from Java 8 to Java 7

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

How to transform this piece of code:

```
private static Map<CustomObj<? extends CustomOtherObj>, CustomEnumeration> map;
    if (map == null) {
        map = Arrays.stream(CustomEnumeration.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.source, x -> x));
    }
```

into Java 7 equivalent? (The `Arrays.stream.collect(Collectors....)` part.

Basically, the above code puts some elements in a map.

Comment: Can you share the solution you are trying to convert this to and what's not working in that.

Comment: It works well on my PC, but my client PC runs java 7 and he can't update it at the moment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simple

```
if (map == null) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    for(CustomEnumeration e : CustomEnumeration.values())
        map.put(e.source, e);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` lambda just performs an action for each element in a collection. So, it is roughly equivalent to a `foreach`-style `for` loop. In other words, see below. I kept `x` (not a great variable name) to show the similarity.

```
if (null == map) {
    map = new HashMap<CustomObj<? extends CustomOtherObj>, CustomEnumeration>();
    for (CustomEnumeration x : CustomEnumeration.values()) {
        map.put(x.source, x);
    }
}
```